# How to get data from firebase with field value?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I Want to get data from firebase as a field like category.means i want  to get data Such in image Field category value is fashion so all items where field category value fashion data are retrive so which query i use for it anyone tell me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this query:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where('category', isEqualTo: 'fashion')
  .get()
  .then(...);
```

I highly recommend reading the FlutterFire documentation on [filtering data](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#filtering), and keeping the reference documentation on the [`where` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) handy.